# How to work on knockout validation localization

Tags: grails, localization, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a view page where i'm validating fields using knockout.js . I want to validate my fields in different country's language like spanish,french etc i.e using localization.
I have added el-GR.js ,fr-FR.js , ru-RU.js etc files into my js folder and referenced them.
Now how can i validate or check into my modalModal.js page?

modalModal.js

```
    ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
    ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders : true,
    messagesOnModified : true,
    insertMessages : true,
    parseInputAttributes : true,
    messageTemplate : null
    });

   var mustEqual = function (val, other) {
   return val == other();
   };

   var modalViewModel= {
   firstName : ko.observable().extend({
    minLength : 2,
    maxLength : 40
    }),
    lastName : ko.observable().extend({
    minLength : 2,
    maxLength : 10
    }),
    organisation : ko.observable().extend({
    minLength : 2,
    maxLength : 40
    }),

    email : ko.observable().extend({ // custom message
    email: true
    }),
    password: ko.observable()
    };

    modalViewModel.confirmPassword = ko.observable().extend({
    validation: { validator: mustEqual, message: 'Passwords do not match.', params: 
    modalViewModel.password }
    });
   modalViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(modalViewModel);

  // Activates knockout.js
   ko.applyBindings(modalViewModel,document.getElementById('light'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this for my latest KO project

I override the KO validation rules and use the Globalize plugin, like

```
ko.validation.rules.number.validator = function (value, validate) {
    return !String.hasValue(value) || (validate && !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value)));
};

ko.validation.rules.date.validator = function (value, validate) {
    return !String.hasValue(value) || (validate && Globalize.parseDate(value) != null);
};
```

edit: btw, there is a bug in the Globalize plugin, it will accept dot (.) as part of a number even if it isn't, i fixed that like this

```
Globalize.orgParaseFloat = Globalize.parseFloat;
Globalize.parseFloat = function (value) {
    value = String(value);

    var culture = this.findClosestCulture();
    var seperatorFound = false;
    for (var i in culture.numberFormat) {
        if (culture.numberFormat[i] == ".") {
            seperatorFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!seperatorFound) {
        value = value.replace(".", "NaN");
    }

    return this.orgParaseFloat(value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying .What If i don't want to use plugins?

Comment: You said that you have included  el-GR.js etc, to me that indicates that you already are using Globalize?

Comment: The el-GR.js file is included with the Knockout Validator plugin, so no you don't need to use the Globalize plugin.  But I'm running into issues when not using that plugin as well.